# Can I ask job related question in any of the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation, jobs

I'm a student who just turned into a job seeker and I have some job related questions. Is it possible that I could post my queries in any of the Stack Exchange sites? If so, in which one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you sure can.  Check out the new [Workplace Stack Exchange site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Just please be sure to give their [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) a quick read before posting any questions.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I have posted my query at workplace.